# TFLearn DNN has the same prediction no matter what the input it

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, tflearn

I'm attempting to use openAI gym to play Space Invaders. The code below works to create training data based on playing matches and learning from them when they have scores greater than the score requirement. I get no errors from generating the data, and have confirmed it is all different with different y/target values. Training the model also gives me no errors. In the testModel function, however, the game continues to play the same action. In fact, even if I feed the NN an array of the correct size full of random ints, it continues to predict the same value.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions/ideas of how to continue. Thanks.

```
import gym
import random
import numpy as np
import tflearn
from tqdm import tqdm
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from statistics import mean, median
from collections import Counter

LR  = 1e-3
env = gym.make('SpaceInvaders-v0')
env.reset()
goal_steps = 25000
score_requirement = 300
initial_games = 2000

def some_random_games_first():
    # for episode in range(5):
    env.reset()
    score = 0
    actions = []
    for t in range(goal_steps):
        # env.render()
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        if action not in actions:
            actions.append(action)

        observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        score+=reward
        if done:
            print("step:", t)
            break
    print("observation:", observation)
    observation = observation.flatten()
    print(observation)

def initial_population():
    training_data = []
    scores = []
    accepted_scores = []
    for _ in tqdm(range(initial_games)):
        score = 0
        game_memory = []
        prev_observation = []
        for _ in range(goal_steps):
            action = random.randrange(0,6)
            #env.render()
            observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

            if len(prev_observation) > 0:
                prev_observation = prev_observation.flatten()
                game_memory.append([prev_observation, action])

            prev_observation = observation
            score += reward
            if done:
                break

        if score >= score_requirement:
            accepted_scores.append(score)
            for data in game_memory:
                if data[1] == 0:
                    output = [1,0,0,0,0,0]
                elif data[1] == 1:
                    output = [0,1,0,0,0,0]
                elif data[1] == 2:
                    output = [0,0,1,0,0,0]
                elif data[1] == 3:
                    output = [0,0,0,1,0,0]
                elif data[1] == 4:
                    output = [0,0,0,0,1,0]
                elif data[1] == 5:
                    output = [0,0,0,0,0,1]

                training_data.append([data[0], output])

        env.reset()
        scores.append(score)

    training_data_save = np.array(training_data)
    np.save('saved.npy', training_data_save)

    print('Average accepted score:', mean(accepted_scores))
    print('Median accepted score:', median(accepted_scores))
    print(Counter(accepted_scores))

    return training_data

def neural_network_model(input_size):
    input_layer = input_data(shape = [None, input_size, 1], name='input')

    fc1 = fully_connected(input_layer, 128, activation='relu')
    fc1 = dropout(fc1, 0.8)

    fc2 = fully_connected(fc1, 128, activation='relu')
    fc2 = dropout(fc2, 0.8)

    # fc3 = fully_connected(fc2, 512, activation='relu')
    # fc3 = dropout(fc3, 0.8)
    #
    # fc4 = fully_connected(fc3, 256, activation='relu')
    # fc4 = dropout(fc4, 0.8)
    #
    # fc5 = fully_connected(fc4, 128, activation='relu')
    # fc5 = dropout(fc5, 0.8)

    fc6 = fully_connected(fc2, 6, activation='softmax')
    network = regression(fc6, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')

    model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_dir='log')

    return model

def train_model(training_data, model=False):
    X = np.array([i[0] for i in training_data]).reshape(-1, len(training_data[0][0]), 1)
    y = [i[1] for i in training_data]

    if not model:
        model = neural_network_model(input_size = len(X[0]))

    model.fit({'input':X}, {'targets':y}, n_epoch=1, snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id='openaistuff')

    return model

def generateData():
    training_data = initial_population()
    print("training data:",training_data[0])

def countActions():
    training_data = np.load('saved.npy')
    X = np.array([np.argmax(i[1]) for i in training_data])
    print(Counter(X))

def testModel(model):
    scores = []
    choices = []

    for each_game in range(1):
        score = 0
        game_memory = []
        prev_obs = []
        env.reset()
        for _ in range(goal_steps):
            if len(prev_obs) == 0:
                action = random.randrange(0,6)
            else:
                prev_obs = prev_obs.flatten()
                action = np.argmax(model.predict(prev_obs.reshape(-1, len(prev_obs), 1)))

            choices.append(action)

            # env.render()
            new_observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
            prev_obs = new_observation
            game_memory.append([new_observation.flatten(), action])
            score += reward
            if done:
                break

        print('Score of game {} was {}'.format(each_game,score))

        scores.append(score)

    print('Average Score', sum(scores)/len(scores))

training_data = np.load('saved.npy')
model = neural_network_model(input_size = len(training_data[0][0]))
model.load('fresh.model')

# print(len(training_data))
# training_data = initial_population()
# model = train_model(training_data)
testModel(model)
# model.save('fresh.model')
```

Answer (score 0):

How long have you been training for?
In my experience with OpenAI, it usually takes a very long time for neural networks to learn anything. This often means that the actor will take only one action.